# Drawing Three Tangential Lines on a TikZ Diagram to a Specific Point on a Circle's Circumference

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw the three red lines shown in the TikZ picture below:

- Line 1: Start from the inner circle's circumference at 0 degrees, extending tangentially to the north, and reach the middle circle.  Position the number '20' along the midway point of this line.
- Line 2: Initiate from the middle circle's circumference at 180
  degrees, extending tangentially to the south, and connect to the
  middle circle. Position the number '21' along the midway point of this line.
- Line 3: Begin from the inner circle's circumference at 270 degrees,   extending tangentially to the east, and reach the outer circle. Place   the letter 'x' at the midway point of this line.

Look at the drawing below for illustration.

**CODE**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw (0,0) circle (1);
        \draw (0,0) circle (2);
        \draw (0,0) circle (2.7);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT (red lines and characters added only for clarification)**:

[image]

**FINAL WORK (Thanks to the community)**:

[image]

Comment: You can use polar coordinate like (-90: 1) for one end.  The intersections library might be the easiest way to find the other ends.  Or use trig and calculate the length needed.

Comment: This is basically a trigonometry question which you like to be solved with TikZ methods? (Positioning a number along a line won't be a problem. That's a core functionality of TikZ.)

Comment: Math problem from Spiegel online a couple of days ago? `:-)`

Comment: Yes thats a Spiegel online Problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments, this is essentially just a practical example of the Pythagorean theorem (note that I shifted the labels so that they are not cut by the circles, but the `$x$` shows how to position a label midway using `midway`):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2];
        \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2.7];

        \draw[red, densely dotted] (3,0) -- (-3,0);
        \draw[red, densely dotted] (0,3) -- (0,-3);

        % a^2 + b^2 = c^2 <=> b = (c^2 - a^2)^0.5

        \draw[red, thick] (1,0) -- (1,{sqrt(2*2-1*1)})
            node[pos=0.75, left] {20};

        \draw[red, thick] (0,-1) -- ({sqrt(2.7*2.7-1*1)},-1)
            node[pos=0.5, above] {$x$};

        \draw[red, thick] (-2,0) -- (-2,{-1*sqrt(2.7*2.7-2*2)})
            node[pos=0.25, left] {21};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Graphical explanation:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{scope}[opacity=0.25]
            \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];
            \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2];
            \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2.7];
    
            \draw[red, densely dotted] (3,0) -- (-3,0);
            \draw[red, densely dotted] (0,3) -- (0,-3);
    
            \draw[red, thick] (1,0) -- (1,{sqrt(2*2-1*1)})
                node[pos=0.75, left] {20};
    
            \draw[red, thick] (0,-1) -- ({sqrt(2.7*2.7-1*1)},-1)
                node[pos=0.5, above] {$x$};
    
            \draw[red, thick] (-2,0) -- (-2,{-1*sqrt(2.7*2.7-2*2)})
                node[pos=0.25, left] {21};
        \end{scope}
    
        \draw[red] (-2,{-1*sqrt(2.7*2.7-2*2)}) 
            |- node[pos=0.25, left] {$b = \sqrt{c^{2} - a^{2}}$} 
               node[pos=0.75, above] {$a = 2$} (0,0) 
            -- node[below right] {$c = 2.7$} cycle;
        \draw[red, very thin] (-2,-0.25) -| (-1.75,0);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Bonus: The very same drawing using the `l3draw` package (positioning of the labels might be a tad different):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \draw_begin:

        \draw_path_circle:nn { 0cm , 0cm } { 1cm }
        \draw_path_circle:nn { 0cm , 0cm } { 2cm }
        \draw_path_circle:nn { 0cm , 0cm } { 2.7cm }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }

        \color_select:n { red }
        \draw_scope_begin:
            \draw_dash_pattern:nn { 1pt } { 0cm }
            \draw_path_moveto:n { 3cm , 0cm }
            \draw_path_lineto:n { -3cm , 0cm }
            \draw_path_moveto:n { 0cm , 3cm }
            \draw_path_lineto:n { 0cm , -3cm }
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
        \draw_scope_end:

        \draw_linewidth:n { 0.8pt }
        \draw_path_moveto:n { 1cm , 0cm }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { 1cm , sqrt(2^2 - 1^2) * 1cm }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }

        \draw_scope_begin:
            \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { 20 }
            \draw_transform_shift:n { 0.9cm , sqrt(2^2 - 1^2) * 0.75cm }
            \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { r } { vc }
        \draw_scope_end:

        \draw_path_moveto:n { 0cm , -1cm }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { sqrt(2.7^2 - 1^2) * 1cm , -1cm }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }

        \draw_scope_begin:
            \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { $x$ }
            \draw_transform_shift:n { sqrt(2.7^2 - 1^2) * 0.5cm , -0.9cm }
            \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { hc } { b }
        \draw_scope_end:

        \draw_path_moveto:n { -2cm , 0cm }
        \draw_path_lineto:n { -2cm , sqrt(2.7^2 - 2^2) * -1cm }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
        
        \draw_scope_begin:
            \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_tmpa_coffin { 21 }
            \draw_transform_shift:n { -2.1cm , sqrt(2.7^2 - 2^2) * -0.25cm }
            \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { r } { vc }
        \draw_scope_end:
        
    \draw_end:
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Chapeau Jasper! I have the same solution...later.(+1)

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer You're welcome. I added a graphical explanation even. Note that I used `2.7*2.7` in the code instead of `2.7^2` which would also work, but TeX is better with multiplication than with calculating powers. Of course, I also wrote `1*1` to make things clear.

Comment: The `\fp_eval:n` shouldn't be necessary. Much like PGF, `l3draw` seems to throw everything into evaluation as well.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel True! Thanks for pointing this out! I proposed that some easier command be defined to position coffins in a drawing. It seems that they are always positioned at the origin. It also seems that `\coffin_typeset:Nnnnn` can be used, but it has a different syntax. Or do you know of some simpler way than my approach?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution where the underlying driver (here PDF) does the math for you by clipping the colored lines against the circles.

The order of the paths are so that the colored lines all are behind the circles.
Of course, this way, the nodes' placement needs to be guesstimated a bit but it's very simple here.

If you need arrow tips at the points where the straight lines touch the circles or need to draw another line to it math will have to get involved (either by you or by TikZ).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \draw[every edge/.append style={densely dotted, red}]
    (left:3) edge (right:3)
    (down:3) edge (up:3)
    (0,0) circle[radius=2.7]
    [path picture={
      \draw[green] (left:2) -- node[near start,left] {$21$} +(down:2.7);
      \draw[red] (down:1) -- node[above] {$x$} +(right:2.7);
      \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2]
        [path picture={
          \draw[blue] (right:1) -- node[right] {$20$} +(up:2);
        }];
      \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];
     }];
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tkz-elements}
\begin{document}
      
\begin{tkzelements}
function pytha (a,b)
   return math.sqrt(a*a-b*b)
end

ra,rb,rc = 1,2,2.7
z.O = point : new ( 0  , 0  )   
z.A = point : new ( ra , 0  )
z.B = point : new ( 0  , -ra  )
z.C = point : new ( -rb  , 0 )
z.D = point : new ( rc , 0  )
z.Ap = z.A : north (pytha(rb,ra))
z.Bp = z.B : east  (pytha(rc,ra))
z.Cp = z.C : south (pytha(rc,rb))
\end{tkzelements}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzGetNodes
\tkzDrawCircles(O,A O,C O,D)
\tkzDrawSegments[red,thick](A,A' B,B' C,C')
\tkzLabelSegment[red,above](B,B'){$x$}
\tkzLabelSegment[red,right](A,A'){$20$}
\tkzLabelSegment[red,left](C,C') {$21$}
\draw[red, densely dotted] (3,0) -- (-3,0)
                           (0,3) -- (0,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Alain for your effort. nice Work.